# Переоткрытие или Повторное открытие

Tags: обсуждение, локализация, переоткрытие-вопросов

В разных контекстах на сайте используются как "переоткрытие" так и "повторное открытие". Не стоит ли привести это название к "общему знаменателю"? Прежде чем ответить для себя на этот вопрос, стоит рассмотреть хотя бы некоторые (а лучше, все возможные) ситуации использования. Примеры того, как это выглядит сейчас:

- Ссылки под закрытым вопросом:

  > [image: закрытый вопрос]
- Вопрос, как реакция на попытку переоткрытия:

  > [image: предложить повторное открытие]
- Очередь проверок:

  > [image: очередь проверок]
- Резолюция по голосованию:

  > [image: резолюция]
- [Метка](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2/info) для вопросов на Мете:

  > [image: метка]

Полный список могут посмотреть обладатели доступа к transifex:

- [повторное открытие](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40262541?qt=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BD%20%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%80)
- [переоткрытие](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40262597?qt=%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA)

Comment: а что такое transifex , и как можно там зарегистрироваться ?

Comment: @stas0k по ссылке в принципе должно быть видно, что это такое. Это сайт для обеспечения перевода ресурсов на разные языки. Чтобы получить доступ к переводам stackoverflow нужно помимо аккаунта на transifex запросить разрешение через форму обратной связи.

Comment: @stas0k ответ здесь: http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1137/181472

Answer (score 2):

> Ссылки под закрытым вопросом:

нужно оставить как есть - по одному слову они гораздо лучше, чем по несколько.

Я бы там ещё один случай с двумя словами постарался бы как-то заменить, но это к вопросу не относится.

> Вопрос, как реакция на попытку переоткрытия:

Это нормально, что в пояснении слово заменено более подробным сочетанием. Всё-таки тут уточняется, действительно ли ты хочешь сделать именно это.

> Метка для вопросов на Мете:

Тоже хорошо смотрится в коротком виде.

> Очередь проверок:

Так вроде звучит красивее, хотя не принципиально.

> Резолюция по голосованию:

Эти две строки должны быть похожи по структуре.

Так выглядит хорошо:
Открыть повторно
Оставить закрытым

Так - не очень:
Переоткрыть
Оставить закрытым

Так - просто непонятно, что "оставить":
Переоткрыть
Оставить
хотя визуально тоже хорошо - если подобрать подходящий глагол, то можно.

> В разных контекстах на сайте используются как "переоткрытие" так и "повторное открытие".

Мне не кажется, что это проблема. В любом языке есть куча синонимов, так что нет причин цепляться к единственному слову или фразе. Люди как использовали оба вариант, так и будут, независимо от того, какое решение мы тут примем.

> Полный список могут посмотреть обладатели доступа к transifex:

У меня нет, так что только по фразам из вопроса.

Comment: Как будут использовать люди это дело каждого лично. Я хотел обсудить именно отображение на страницах сайта.